# htaccess don't work on cpanel but worked fine on wampserver

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, localhost, cpanel, wampserver

i am facing an error when i try to post my website on a server that use cpanel, the website worked fine works fine in wampserver , i think the problem might came from the htaccess file wich generate for me a 500 error

here is my htaccess

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /  (because my files are in public_html)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

it's my first time on stackoverflow please help me

Answer (score 1):

In case someone passed by here just remove the php_flag and php_value from yout .htaccess because some hosting compagnies don't allow users to use them, like in my case